# Move trunk/tags/branches to a subfolder

Tags: svn

I would like to go from the structure

```
root
  - branches
  - tags
  - trunk
```

to

```
root
  - new
    - branches
    - tags
    - trunk
  - old
    - branches
    - tags
    - trunk
```

however if i try to move an existing folder (eg. root\trunk) to root\old\trunk

TortoiseSVN is warning me about "moving a special" folder.

will I run into problems by doing so, or is it ok to change it the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem would be that old links or scripts refering to the old version are not working anymore.

Tortoise issues only a warning, as normal users in normal workprocess should not do this.

SVN is fully transparent about moving the tags/branches/trunk folder.. and so is TortoiseSVN